# Convert varchar of HH:MM:SS to minutes value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

Using SQL Server, I have a column with `varchar` data coming from another source that is formatted in pseudo HH:MM:SS string representing a duration time like:

```
Duration
HH:MM:SS
00:43:46
01:30:06
43:56:38
89:24:00
5890:01:00
```

I wanted to convert it to a simple minutes (`int`) value for each

```
Duration    MinuteDuration
HH:MM:SS    mm
00:43:46    43
01:30:06    90
43:56:38    2636
89:24:00    5364
5890:01:00  353401
```

I looked around stackoverflow and found several people suggesting CONVERT with the TIME param

```
    USE [MyDB]
    GO

    SELECT [User],
          [Duration],
          (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, Duration, 8)) as DurationMinutes,
      FROM [dbo].[MyTable]

    GO
```

but I cannot use that since my hours values may be larger than 24/12 (my hours value could be in the thousands).  Since the original data is in a `varchar`, I need to interpret the string first, then multiple the hours by 60* and add it to the minutes value (and just drop the seconds value).

Comment: So your last paragraph explains what you need to do? Which bit of that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although parsing the components of the time is definitely a possibility, the string manipulation is pretty simple too:

```
select duration,
       (convert(int, left(duration, charindex(':', duration) - 1)) * 60 +
        convert(int, left(right(duration, 5), 2))
       )
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=973ba68c474e91d2d227085b06645921) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `ParseName()` in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Duration] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('00:43:46')
,('01:30:06')
,('43:56:38')
,('89:24:00')
,('5890:01:00')

Select A.Duration
      ,Minutes = parsename(NewValue,2) + (parsename(NewValue,3)*60)
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(Duration,':','.') ) ) B(NewValue)
```

**Returns**

```
Duration    Minutes
00:43:46    43
01:30:06    90
43:56:38    2636
89:24:00    5364
5890:01:00  353401
```